# How can I get more information why publish fails?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish, web-deployment

I currently try to deploy a ASP.NET application with Visual Studio 2012. I created a publish profile, validated the connection (got this green checkmark) and clicked on "Publish". I with the same information and with FileZilla, I can create files / folders.

But I get this error:

```
2>------ Publish started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Connecting to my.url.de...
2>Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\moose\MyProject\MyProject\Web.Debug.config into obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.
2>Publishing folder /...
2>Unable to add 'Global.asax' to the Web site.   (550).
2>Unable to add 'NamespaceComments.xml' to the Web site.   (550).
2>Unable to add 'packages.config' to the Web site.   (550).
2>Unable to add 'Web.config' to the Web site.   (550).
2>Unable to add folder 'bin' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "bin".
2>Unable to add folder 'CodeTemplates' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "CodeTemplates".
2>Unable to add folder 'Content' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Content".
2>Unable to add folder 'Models' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Models".
2>Unable to add folder 'Views' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Views".
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I know that FTP-Error 550 means: *Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).* ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes))

This doesn't give me any hint why he is "Unable to add [xyz]". How can I get more information about it? 
(For example, where did VS try to deploy it?)

Comment: I got the error (I needed to change to folder on the server, as I didn't have write-rights for the folder / but for some sub-folder). But the problem, that I don't get much information still remains.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I realized I forgot to start my Visual Studio as Administrator. As soon as I did, the problem with publishing was gone.